# DB2 LUW 11.5.9 dbprereqcheck: 'The db2prereqcheck utility failed to find the following package or file: ""'

Tags: db2, upgrade, db2-luw

I am trying to upgrade my DB-2 LUW 11.5.6 community edition (free license) installation, originally created on a CentOS 7 Linux x86_64 host, to the latest 11.5.9 version.

The instructions say to cd to the 'server_dec' directory unpacked from the tarfile, and run './db2setup', which I am doing.

I have downloaded the v11.5.9_linuxx64_server_dec.tar.gz file, and am
trying to follow the instructions, with a running DB-2 11.5.6 instance, and the /opt/ibm/db2/V11.5/{bin,adm,instance} directories in my $PATH, as 'root' (the user I installed it as originally) . The old v11.5.6 installer did recognize Centos-7 OK, but now the new installer is having problems recognizing the new Rocky RHEL8 OS I have installed, and a coredump of the installer is generated.

Running 'db2/linuxamd/install/db2prereqcheck' produces a log with NO
features enabled for installation, and messages like:

```
==========================================================================

Thu Nov 30 17:40:30 2023
Checking prerequisites for DB2 installation. Version "11.5.9.0". Operating system "Linux" 

Validating "kernel level " ... 
   Required minimum operating system kernel level: "3.10.0". 
   Actual operating system kernel level: "4.18.0". 
   Requirement matched. 

Validating "Linux distribution " ... 
   Required minimum operating system distribution: "CENTOS"; Version: "7"; Service pack: "9". 
   Actual operating system distribution Version: "8"; Service pack: "9". 
   Requirement matched. 

Validating "Bin user" ... 
   Requirement matched. 

Validating "C++ Library version " ... 
   Required minimum C++ library: "libstdc++.so.6" 
   Standard C++ library is located in the following directory: "/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.25". 
   Actual C++ library: "CXXABI_1.3.1" 
   Requirement matched. 


Validating "32 bit version of "libstdc++.so.6" " ... 
   Found the 32 bit "/lib/libstdc++.so.6" in the following directory "/lib". 
   Requirement matched. 

Validating "libaio.so version " ... 
DBT3553I  The db2prereqcheck utility successfully loaded the libaio.so.1 file. 
   Requirement matched. 

Validating "libnuma.so version " ... 
DBT3610I  The db2prereqcheck utility successfully loaded the libnuma.so.1 file. 
   Requirement matched. 

Validating "/lib/libpam.so*" ... 
   Requirement matched. 
DBT3533I  The db2prereqcheck utility has confirmed that all installation prerequisites were met. 

==========================================================================

Thu Nov 30 17:40:30 2023
Checking prerequisites for DB2 installation with the DB2 pureScale Feature.  Version: "11.5.9.0".  Operating system: "Linux". 

Validating "kernel level " ... 
   Required minimum operating system kernel level: "3.10.0". 
   Actual operating system kernel level: "4.18.0". 
   Requirement matched. 

Validating "Linux distribution " ... 
   Required minimum operating system distribution: "CENTOS"; Version: "7"; Service pack: "9". 
   Actual operating system distribution Version: "8"; Service pack: "9". 
   Requirement matched. 

Validating "ksh symbolic link" ... 
   Requirement matched. 

Validating "Bin user" ... 
   Requirement matched. 

Validating "SELinux status " ... 
   SELinux is "disabled ". 
   Requirement matched. 

Validating "libc.so version " ... 
   glibc library is located in the following directory "/usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so". 
   Required minimum glibc library version: "2.4.0" 
   Actual glibc library version: "2.28.0" 
   Requirement matched. 

Validating "gcc" ... 
   Package (or file) found: "gcc" 
   Requirement matched. 

Validating "binutils" ... 
   Package (or file) found: "binutils" 
   Requirement matched. 

Validating "cpp" ... 
   Package (or file) found: "cpp" 
   Requirement matched. 

Validating "gcc-c++" ... 
   Package (or file) found: "gcc-c++" 
   Requirement matched. 

Validating "" ... 
DBT3507E  The db2prereqcheck utility failed to find the following package or file: "". 
   ERROR : Requirement not matched. 

Validating "" ... 
DBT3507E  The db2prereqcheck utility failed to find the following package or file: "". 
   ERROR : Requirement not matched. 

Validating "kernel-source" ... 
DBT3507E  The db2prereqcheck utility failed to find the following package or file: "kernel-source". 
   ERROR : Requirement not matched. 

Validating "prereqSAM" ... 
DBT3613E  The db2prereqcheck utility failed to verify the prerequisites for TSA. Ensure your machine meets all the TSA installation prerequisites. 
   ERROR : Requirement not matched. 

Validating "free space" ... 
The directory "/tmp" has enough space on host "devbox01.ptti.co.uk". 
   Requirement matched. 

Validating "free space" ... 
The directory "/var" has enough space on host "devbox01.ptti.co.uk". 
   Requirement matched. 

Validating "free space" ... 
The directory "/usr" has enough space on host "devbox01.ptti.co.uk". 
   Requirement matched. 
Requirement not matched for DB2 dash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `rpm -q --qf "%{NAME}\n%{VERSION}\n%{RELEASE}\n" -l (null) 2>&1 > /tmp/db2prereqcheck.240655'
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `rpm -q --qf "%{NAME}\n%{VERSION}\n%{RELEASE}\n" -l (null) 2>&1 > /tmp/db2prereqcheck.240655'
tabase "Server" with pureScale feature . Version: "11.5.9.0". 
Summary of prerequisites that are not met on the current system: 
DBT3613E  The db2prereqcheck utility failed to verify the prerequisites for TSA. Ensure your machine meets all the TSA installation prerequisites. 


DBT3507E  The db2prereqcheck utility failed to find the following package or file: "kernel-source". 


DBT3507E  The db2prereqcheck utility failed to find the following package or file: "". 


DBT3507E  The db2prereqcheck utility failed to find the following package or file: "". 



==========================================================================
```

db2setup coredump :

```
[root@devbox01 server_dec]# ./db2setup
DBI1190I  db2setup is preparing the DB2 Setup wizard which will guide
  you through the program setup process. Please wait.


Nov 30 18:15:03 devbox01.ptti.co.uk org.gnome.Shell.desktop[8325]: Window manager warning: Window 0x3000020 sets an MWM hint indicating it isn't resizable, but sets min size 1 x 1 and max size 2147483647 x 2147483647; this doesn't make much sense.
Nov 30 18:15:03 devbox01.ptti.co.uk org.gnome.Shell.desktop[8325]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x3000007 specified for 0x3000020.
Nov 30 18:15:03 devbox01.ptti.co.uk org.gnome.Shell.desktop[8325]: Window manager warning: Window 0x3000020 sets an MWM hint indicating it isn't resizable, but sets min size 1 x 1 and max size 2147483647 x 2147483647; this doesn't make much sense.
Nov 30 18:15:13 devbox01.ptti.co.uk java[248622]: IBM Java[248622]: JVMDUMP039I Processing dump event "gpf", detail "" at 2023/11/30 18:15:13 - please wait.
Nov 30 18:15:13 devbox01.ptti.co.uk java[248622]: IBM Java[248622]: JVMDUMP032I JVM requested System dump using '/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/install/core.20231130.181513.248622.0001.dmp' in response to an event
Nov 30 18:15:13 devbox01.ptti.co.uk systemd[1]: Started Process Core Dump (PID 250076/UID 0).
Nov 30 18:15:14 devbox01.ptti.co.uk systemd-coredump[250077]: Process 250075 (main) of user 0 dumped core.

                              Stack trace of thread 250075:
                              #0  0x00007f29624419e5 __pthread_kill (libpthread.so.0)
                              #1  0x00007f296044cb2d omrdump_create (/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/java/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/libj9prt29.so)
                              #2  0x00007f294ee0db32 doSystemDump (/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/java/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/libj9dmp29.so)
                              #3  0x00007f294ee09945 protectedDumpFunction (/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/java/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/libj9dmp29.so)
                              #4  0x00007f2960416a33 omrsig_protect (/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/java/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/libj9prt29.so)
                              #5  0x00007f294ee0cf9b runDumpFunction (/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/java/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/libj9dmp29.so)
                              #6  0x00007f294ee0d12f runDumpAgent (/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/java/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/libj9dmp29.so)
                              #7  0x00007f294ee25066 triggerDumpAgents (/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/java/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/libj9dmp29.so)
                              #8  0x00007f2960b6d972 generateDiagnosticFiles (/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/java/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/libj9vm29.so)
                              #9  0x00007f2960416a33 omrsig_protect (/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/java/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/libj9prt29.so)
                              #10 0x00007f2960b6db85 vmSignalHandler (/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/java/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/libj9vm29.so)
                              #11 0x00007f2960415efa mainSynchSignalHandler (/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/java/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/libj9prt29.so)
                              #12 0x00007f2962444c90 __restore_rt (libpthread.so.0)
                              #13 0x00007f28e97301c7 n/a (/home/adm-jason/Downloads/DB2/server_dec/db2/linuxamd64/install/libdb2ure.so.1)
                              #14 0x00007f28e96e4c02 n/a (/home/adm-jason/Downloads/DB2/server_dec/db2/linuxamd64/install/libdb2ure.so.1)
                              #15 0x00007f28e94c7bc1 n/a (/home/adm-jason/Downloads/DB2/server_dec/db2/linuxamd64/install/libdb2ure.so.1)
                              #16 0x00007f28e94c8705 n/a (/home/adm-jason/Downloads/DB2/server_dec/db2/linuxamd64/install/libdb2ure.so.1)
                              #17 0x00007f28e95ac063 n/a (/home/adm-jason/Downloads/DB2/server_dec/db2/linuxamd64/install/libdb2ure.so.1)
                              #18 0x00007f2960c15aaa ffi_call_unix64 (/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/java/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/libj9vm29.so)
                              #19 0x00007f2960c11f3c ffi_call_int (/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/java/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/libj9vm29.so)
                              #20 0x00007f2960ac3792 _ZN32VM_BytecodeInterpreterCompressed3runEP10J9VMThread (/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/java/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/libj9vm29.so)
                              #21 0x00007f2960ab3cbc bytecodeLoopCompressed (/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/java/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/libj9vm29.so)
                              #22 0x00007f2960ba85f2 c_cInterpreter (/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/java/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/libj9vm29.so)
                              #23 0x00007f2960b5602a runCallInMethod (/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/java/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/libj9vm29.so)
                              #24 0x00007f2960b712f9 gpProtectedRunCallInMethod (/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/java/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/libj9vm29.so)
                              #25 0x00007f2960416a33 omrsig_protect (/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/java/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/libj9prt29.so)
                              #26 0x00007f2960bb31ac gpProtectAndRun (/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/java/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/libj9vm29.so)
                              #27 0x00007f2960b72ba4 gpCheckCallin (/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/java/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/libj9vm29.so)
                              #28 0x00007f2960b70cca callStaticVoidMethod (/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/java/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/libj9vm29.so)
                              #29 0x00007f29622203fb JavaMain (/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/java/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so)
                              #30 0x00007f296243a1ea start_thread (libpthread.so.0)
                              #31 0x00007f2961c81e33 __clone (libc.so.6)
Nov 30 18:15:14 devbox01.ptti.co.uk systemd[1]: systemd-coredump@3-250076-0.service: Succeeded.
Nov 30 18:15:15 devbox01.ptti.co.uk abrtd[877]: Size of '/var/spool/abrt' >= 5000 MB (MaxCrashReportsSize), deleting old directory 'ccpp-2023-11-30-17:29:10.275390-240194'
Nov 30 18:15:16 devbox01.ptti.co.uk abrt-server[250086]: Sending a notification email to: "root@localhost"
Nov 30 18:15:20 devbox01.ptti.co.uk java[248622]: IBM Java[248622]: JVMDUMP012E Error in System dump: /root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/install/core.20231130.181513.248622.0001.dmp
Nov 30 18:15:20 devbox01.ptti.co.uk java[248622]: IBM Java[248622]: JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Java dump using '/tmp/javacore.20231130.181513.248622.0002.txt' in response to an event
Nov 30 18:15:20 devbox01.ptti.co.uk java[248622]: IBM Java[248622]: JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Snap dump using '/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/install/Snap.20231130.181513.248622.0003.trc' in response to an event
Nov 30 18:15:20 devbox01.ptti.co.uk java[248622]: IBM Java[248622]: JVMDUMP032I JVM requested JIT dump using '/root/db2.tmp.245351/db2/linuxamd64/install/jitdump.20231130.181513.248622.0004.dmp' in response to an event
[root@devbox01 server_dec]#
```

How to meet these missing prerequisites?

```
DBT3507E  The db2prereqcheck utility failed to find the following package or file: "kernel-source". 

DBT3507E  The db2prereqcheck utility failed to find the following package or file: "". 

DBT3507E  The db2prereqcheck utility failed to find the following package or file: "".
```

'kernel-source' is not a package. I have 'kernel-devel' and 'kernel-debugsource' installed.

What the IBM DB-2 LUW v11.5.9 empty requirement '""' is?

Or how to successfully install DB2 LUW Server v11.5.9 over v11.5.6, retaining existing DBs, on a Rocky RHEL8 x86_64 host?

Comment: if interested you can run a trace of the db2prereqcheck and study its output (particularly for fopen failures etc) using whatever is your favourite available tracing tool on that distro . If you do not intend to use TSA then consider using the `-i` option to db2prereqcheck.  But also study this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/333207/db2-v11-5-9-0-installation-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libaws-cpp-sdk/333315#333315

Comment: Thanks, @mao - I did check that all of 'awscli', 'fence-agents-aws', 'libcurl{,-devel}', 'libxml{,-devel}', 'sg3_utils', 'ksh', and 'dash' packages are installed. I do not have any AWS SDK libraries installed as for dba.stackexchange.com/questions/333207/ . 

I am using 'strace -s8192 -v -e trace=execve ./db2/linuxamd/install/db2prereqcheck',  the log is very large, it does not currently show anything obvious .
Will run without the '-e trace=exeve' (or with '-e trace=open,openat,access,execve', that will show any files it is failing to open, but still nothing obvious found ...

Comment: I am going though the enormous (22MB) db2prereqcheck strace log I generated, 
but nothing obvious found so far .

My main concern is not the db2prereqcheck, but the dbsetup GUI coredump .

I just want to install the non-PureScale, non-TSA FreeWare v11.5.9 Server -
according to dbprereqcheck, all requirements should be met for that feature -
it is only the TSA and PureScale enabled server features that are disabled.

So why doesn't db2setup get past the Splash Screen phase and allow me to do anything ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not a very good answer, but should be able to be made to work :

Having unpacked the tarfile, cd to the 'server_dec/db2/linuxamd64/FILES' directory, and run
this command:

```
[root@host] # for f in ACS_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_TOOLS_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz BASE_CLIENT_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz BASE_DB2_ENGINE_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz BASE_CLIENT_R_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz BASE_DB2_ENGINE_R_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz CF_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz CLIENT_PRODUCT_SIGNATURE_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz  CLPPLUS_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz  COMMUNICATION_SUPPORT_TCPIP_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz CONNECT_SUPPORT_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz CONSV_PRODUCT_SIGNATURE_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz  DATABASE_PARTITIONING_SUPPORT_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz  DB2_CONTROL_CENTER_HELP_EN_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz DB2_DATA_SOURCE_SUPPORT_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz DB2_JAVA_HELP_EN_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz DB2_PRODUCT_MESSAGES_EN_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz EDB_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz ESE_PRODUCT_SIGNATURE_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz FED_DATA_SOURCE_SUPPORT_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz FIRST_STEPS_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz GSK_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz GSK_CRYPTO_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz GUARDIUM_INST_MNGR_CLIENT_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz ICU_SUP_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz IINR_APPLICATIONS_WRAPPER_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz IINR_SCIENTIFIC_WRAPPER_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz IINR_STRUCTURED_FILES_WRAPPER_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz INFORMIX_DATA_SOURCE_SUPPORT_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz INSTANCE_SETUP_SUPPORT_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz  ITLM_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz JAVA_COMMON_FILES_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz JAVA_RUNTIME_SUPPORT_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz JAVA_SUPPORT_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz JDBC_DATA_SOURCE_SUPPORT_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz JDK_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz LDAP_EXPLOITATION_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz ODBC_DATA_SOURCE_SUPPORT_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz ORACLE_DATA_SOURCE_SUPPORT_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz RELATIONAL_WRAPPERS_COMMON_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz REPL_CLIENT_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz  RTCL_PRODUCT_SIGNATURE_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz SPATIAL_EXTENDER_CLIENT_SUPPORT_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz SPATIAL_EXTENDER_SERVER_SUPPORT_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz SQL_PROCEDURES_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz SQL_SERVER_DATA_SOURCE_SUPPORT_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz  SYBASE_DATA_SOURCE_SUPPORT_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz TERADATA_DATA_SOURCE_SUPPORT_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz TEXT_SEARCH_11.5.9.0_linuxamd64_x86_64.tar.gz ; do echo '*** '$f;  gunzip < "$f" | (cd /opt/IBM/db2/V11.5/; tar -xpvf -); done 2>&1 | tee ~/db2-upgrade.log
```

OK, that will unpack all the files into your installation directory .

Then, as described at :

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.1.0?topic=servers-installing-payload-files

and

https://www.ordinatechnic.com/web-cloud-server/1/Software/2/RDBMS/3/IBM%20Db2/getting-started-with-ibm-db2-on-linux-part-iii-manual-installation

run:

```
[root@host] # $DB2DIR/install/db2chgpath 
...
```

Then the install SHOULD be updated and SHOULD work - testing now.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, db2prereqcheck by default will check all possible version requirements, some of which may not be relevant to your installation.

You can use the specific version to just check the 11.5.9.0 requirements:

e.g.
db2prereqcheck -i -v '11.5.9.0' -s